# MySQL sum of column by distinct hostname and by latest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 DATE       | HOSTNAME | MY_VALUE
 -----------+----------+----------
 2015-08-10 | host01   | 1
 2015-08-10 | host02   | 3
 2015-08-10 | host03   | 4
 2015-08-11 | host01   | 7
 2015-08-12 | host02   | 13
```

I want to get the sum of the last `MY_VALUE` from each distinct `hostname` by most recent date. The output should be '`24`' (4+7+13).

```
SELECT sum(MY_VALUE) 
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(My_Value)
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.`Date` = (
  SELECT Max(ti.`Date`)
  FROM Table1 ti
  WHERE t.`HostName` = ti.`HostName`);
```

[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be43b/3)

Answer (score 0):

When you say the most recent date it means you want only one record Hostname. You can go with row number analytical function.

```
select sum(myvalue),hostname 
select hostname,date,myvalue,row_number() over (partition by hostname order by date) as n 
from table ) 
where n=1
```

If still you don't get an answer. Could you please explain  your requirement

Comment: Your query has many syntax errors ;).